# Drawing arrows from different edges of node/decision box

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I'm new to tikz and don't understand how to draw lines originating from all edges of a decision box to other nodes.

In the diagram below [image: flow chart],
how can I specify the originating point of an arrow? For e.g I want to draw an arrow from the bottom of Decision1 to the left edge of Decision2 but just can't figure out how.

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=6.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=10em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{mycircle} = [circle, thick, draw=orange, minimum height=4mm]

\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
    minimum height=2em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center,node distance = 2cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (init) {Read system data};
    \node [block, right of=init, node distance=6cm] (trip) {Trip};

    \node [block, below of=init, node distance=2.7cm] (setloadavg)
             {Set average loading level to L\textsubscript{avg}=[0.8,0.9,1,1.1]};
    \node [decision, right of=setloadavg, node distance=6cm] (decision2) {Decision2};
    \node [block, right of=decision2, node distance=3cm] (stop1) {Stop};

    \node [block, below of=setloadavg, node distance=3cm] (setk) {Set K};
    \node [decision, right of=setk, node distance=6cm] (decision3) {Decision3};
    \node [mycircle, right of=decision3, node distance=4cm] (circle1) {1};

    \node [block, below of=setk, node distance=2cm] (startsim)
        {Start simulation (run 1) to generate cascade data, K=0};
    \node [block, right of=startsim, node distance=6cm] (increment) {Increment};
    \node [mycircle, left of=startsim, node distance=4cm] (circle2) {2};

    \node [block, below of=startsim, node distance=3cm] (setloadlevel) {Set Load level};
    \node [decision, right of=setloadlevel, node distance=6cm] (decision4) {Decision4};
    \node [mycircle, right of=decision4, node distance=4cm] (circle3) {2};

    \node [block, below of=setloadlevel, node distance=3cm] (runloadflow) {Run load flow};
    \node [block, right of=runloadflow, node distance=6cm] (stop2) {stop};

    \node [decision, below of=runloadflow, node distance=3cm] (decision1) {Decision1};
    \node [mycircle, left of=decision1, node distance=4cm] (circle2) {1};


    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (init) -- (setloadavg);
    \path [line] (setloadavg) -- (setk);
    \path [line] (setk) -- (startsim);
    \path [line] (startsim) -- (setloadlevel);
    %\path [line] (startsim) -- (circle2);
    \path [line] (setloadlevel) -- (runloadflow);
    \path [line] (runloadflow) -- (decision1);
    \path [line] (decision1) -- node [near start] {Yes} +(3,0) |-  (trip);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would appreciate some explanation of the solution and pointers to documentation, if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20,
    text width=6.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20,
    text width=10em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{mycircle} = [circle, thick, draw=orange, minimum height=4mm]

\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
    minimum height=2em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center,node distance = 2cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (init) {Read system data};
    \node [block, right of=init, node distance=6cm] (trip) {Trip};

    \node [block, below of=init, node distance=2.7cm] (setloadavg)
             {Set average loading level to L\textsubscript{avg}=[0.8,0.9,1,1.1]};
    \node [decision, right of=setloadavg, node distance=6cm] (decision2) {Decision2};
    \node [block, right of=decision2, node distance=3cm] (stop1) {Stop};

    \node [block, below of=setloadavg, node distance=3cm] (setk) {Set K};
    \node [decision, right of=setk, node distance=6cm] (decision3) {Decision3};
    \node [mycircle, right of=decision3, node distance=4cm] (circle1) {1};

    \node [block, below of=setk, node distance=2cm] (startsim)
        {Start simulation (run 1) to generate cascade data, K=0};
    \node [block, right of=startsim, node distance=6cm] (increment) {Increment};
    \node [mycircle, left of=startsim, node distance=4cm] (circle2) {2};

    \node [block, below of=startsim, node distance=3cm] (setloadlevel) {Set Load level};
    \node [decision, right of=setloadlevel, node distance=6cm] (decision4) {Decision4};
    \node [mycircle, right of=decision4, node distance=4cm] (circle3) {2};

    \node [block, below of=setloadlevel, node distance=3cm] (runloadflow) {Run load flow};
    \node [block, right of=runloadflow, node distance=6cm] (stop2) {stop};

    \node [decision, below of=runloadflow, node distance=3cm] (decision1) {Decision1};
    \node [mycircle, left of=decision1, node distance=4cm] (circle2) {1};


    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (init) -- (setloadavg);
    \path [line] (setloadavg) -- (setk);
    \path [line] (setk) -- (startsim);
    \path [line] (startsim) -- (setloadlevel);
    %\path [line] (startsim) -- (circle2);
    \path [line] (setloadlevel) -- (runloadflow);
    \path [line] (runloadflow) -- (decision1);
    \path [line] (decision1) -- node [near start] {Yes} +(3,0) coordinate (my coord) |-  (trip);
    \path [line] (decision1.south) -- +(0,-20pt) -| ([xshift=5pt, yshift=-5pt]my coord) |- (decision2.west);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

By placing a coordinate on the previous line, we can navigate around it when placing the new arrow's path. `.south` and `.west` are anchors of the nodes `decision1` and `decision2`, corresponding to the exit and entry point you want. Using the `xshift...,yshift...` ensures that the line goes near to the previous one, without being right on top of it.

Note that some of your syntax is outdated. For example, you should use `\tikzset` rather than `\tikzstyle`.

[image: additional arrow]

Comment: @linuxfan Your question made it really easy to help: your code compiled without any complications, and your question explained exactly what you needed help with.