# Add text on arrow in flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

> Followup-question of [Drawing arrows from different edges of node/decision box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218643/drawing-arrows-from-different-edges-of-node-decision-box)

The problem I have seems pretty simple, but I wasn't able to find a solution in the archives or elsewhere. The output of my `.tex` file is the flowchart below:

[image: Flowchart]

I want to add the text "No" on the vertical line emerging from the bottom-most decision box on the left (with text "Check for line overloads"). It can also be placed on the horizontal line such that it is right below the "Yes".

I added the text "{No}" in a few places but all of them lead to compile errors. Can someone please show me the right way to get this working?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=6.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=15em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{mycircle} = [circle, thick, draw=orange, minimum height=4mm]

\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
    minimum height=2em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center,node distance = 2cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (init) {Read generation, load and transmission line parameters\\
P, V, X};
    \node [block, right of=init, node distance=6cm] (trip) {Trip the overloaded line, NF=NF+1};

    \node [block, below of=init, text width=10em, node distance=2.7cm] (setloadavg)
             {Set average loading level to L\textsubscript{avg}=0.8};
    \node [decision, right of=setloadavg, node distance=6cm] (decision2) {Is NF$>$M};
    \node [block, right of=decision2, node distance=4.5cm] (stop1) {Stop simulation,\\
 K=K+1};
    \node [mycircle, below of=stop1, node distance=2cm] (circle5) {2};

    \node [block, below of=setloadavg, node distance=3cm] (setk) {Set saturation M, Total time of simulation T, No.of Iterations NI};
    \node [decision, right of=setk, node distance=6cm] (decision3) {Is t\textsubscript{run}$<$T};
    \node [mycircle, right of=decision3, node distance=4cm] (circle1) {1};

    \node [block, below of=setk, node distance=2.5cm] (startsim)
        {Start dc loadflow, start time counter  t\textsubscript{run} };
    \node [block, right of=startsim,  text width=5em, node distance=6cm] (increment) {K=K+1};
    \node [mycircle, left of=startsim, node distance=4cm] (circle2) {2};

    \node [block, below of=startsim, node distance=3cm] (setloadlevel) {Set Load level as L\textsubscript{avg}$+$r\textsubscript{ravg},  r\textsubscript{ravg}$\epsilon$ $[-0.5, 0.5]$};
    \node [decision, right of=setloadlevel, node distance=6cm] (decision4) {Is K$<$NI};
    \node [mycircle, right of=decision4, node distance=4cm] (circle4) {2};

    \node [block, below of=setloadlevel, node distance=3cm] (runloadflow) {Trip random line at time t\textsubscript{i}, no. of failures NF=1};
    \node [block, right of=runloadflow, text width=5em, node distance=6cm] (stop2) {STOP};

    \node [decision, below of=runloadflow, node distance=3cm] (decision1) {Check for line overloads?};
    \node [mycircle, left of=decision1, node distance=4cm] (circle3) {1};


    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (init) -- (setloadavg);
    \path [line] (setloadavg) -- (setk);
    \path [line] (setk) -- (startsim);
    \path [line] (startsim) -- (setloadlevel);
    \path [line]  (circle2)--(startsim);
    \path [line] (setloadlevel) -- (runloadflow);
    \path [line] (runloadflow) -- (decision1);
    \path [line] (decision1) -- node [near start] {Yes} +(3,0) |-  (trip);
    \path [line] (decision1) -- node [near start] {Yes} +(3,0) coordinate (my coord) |-  (trip);
    \path [line] (decision1.south) -- +(0,-10pt) -| ([xshift=20pt, yshift=-5pt]my coord)|- (decision3.west);
    %\path [line] (decision1) -- (circle3);
\path [line] (circle3)-- (decision1);

    \path [line] (decision2) -- node [near start] {Yes} (stop1);
    \path [line] (decision2) -- node [near start] {No} (decision3);
    \path [line] (stop1) -- node [near start] {Yes} (circle5);

    \path [line] (decision3) -- node [near start] {No} (increment);
    \path [line] (decision3) -- node [near start] {Yes} (circle1);
    \path [line] (increment) -- (decision4);
   \path [line] (trip) -- (decision2);
    \path [line] (decision4) -- node [near start] {Yes} (circle4);
    \path [line] (decision4) --   node [near start] {No}(stop2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant line is

```
    \path [line] (decision1.south) -- +(0,-10pt) -| node [near start] {No} ([xshift=20pt, yshift=-5pt]my coord)|- (decision3.west);
```

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=6.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=15em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{mycircle} = [circle, thick, draw=orange, minimum height=4mm]

\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
    minimum height=2em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center,node distance = 2cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (init) {Read generation, load and transmission line parameters\\
P, V, X};
    \node [block, right of=init, node distance=6cm] (trip) {Trip the overloaded line, NF=NF+1};

    \node [block, below of=init, text width=10em, node distance=2.7cm] (setloadavg)
             {Set average loading level to L\textsubscript{avg}=0.8};
    \node [decision, right of=setloadavg, node distance=6cm] (decision2) {Is NF$>$M};
    \node [block, right of=decision2, node distance=4.5cm] (stop1) {Stop simulation,\\
 K=K+1};
    \node [mycircle, below of=stop1, node distance=2cm] (circle5) {2};

    \node [block, below of=setloadavg, node distance=3cm] (setk) {Set saturation M, Total time of simulation T, No.of Iterations NI};
    \node [decision, right of=setk, node distance=6cm] (decision3) {Is t\textsubscript{run}$<$T};
    \node [mycircle, right of=decision3, node distance=4cm] (circle1) {1};

    \node [block, below of=setk, node distance=2.5cm] (startsim)
        {Start dc loadflow, start time counter  t\textsubscript{run} };
    \node [block, right of=startsim,  text width=5em, node distance=6cm] (increment) {K=K+1};
    \node [mycircle, left of=startsim, node distance=4cm] (circle2) {2};

    \node [block, below of=startsim, node distance=3cm] (setloadlevel) {Set Load level as L\textsubscript{avg}$+$r\textsubscript{ravg},  r\textsubscript{ravg}$\epsilon$ $[-0.5, 0.5]$};
    \node [decision, right of=setloadlevel, node distance=6cm] (decision4) {Is K$<$NI};
    \node [mycircle, right of=decision4, node distance=4cm] (circle4) {2};

    \node [block, below of=setloadlevel, node distance=3cm] (runloadflow) {Trip random line at time t\textsubscript{i}, no. of failures NF=1};
    \node [block, right of=runloadflow, text width=5em, node distance=6cm] (stop2) {STOP};

    \node [decision, below of=runloadflow, node distance=3cm] (decision1) {Check for line overloads?};
    \node [mycircle, left of=decision1, node distance=4cm] (circle3) {1};


    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (init) -- (setloadavg);
    \path [line] (setloadavg) -- (setk);
    \path [line] (setk) -- (startsim);
    \path [line] (startsim) -- (setloadlevel);
    \path [line]  (circle2)--(startsim);
    \path [line] (setloadlevel) -- (runloadflow);
    \path [line] (runloadflow) -- (decision1);
    \path [line] (decision1) -- node [near start] {Yes} +(3,0) |-  (trip);
    \path [line] (decision1) -- node [near start] {Yes} +(3,0) coordinate (my coord) |-  (trip);
    \path [line] (decision1.south) -- +(0,-10pt) -| node [near start] {No} ([xshift=20pt, yshift=-5pt]my coord)|- (decision3.west);
    %\path [line] (decision1) -- (circle3);
\path [line] (circle3)-- (decision1);

    \path [line] (decision2) -- node [near start] {Yes} (stop1);
    \path [line] (decision2) -- node [near start] {No} (decision3);
    \path [line] (stop1) -- node [near start] {Yes} (circle5);

    \path [line] (decision3) -- node [near start] {No} (increment);
    \path [line] (decision3) -- node [near start] {Yes} (circle1);
    \path [line] (increment) -- (decision4);
   \path [line] (trip) -- (decision2);
    \path [line] (decision4) -- node [near start] {Yes} (circle4);
    \path [line] (decision4) --   node [near start] {No}(stop2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @linuxfan You're welcome :) Take a look also at the "Yes" node, you have two different nodes that are printed one above the other, that's why in my screenshot the "No" looks thinner.